# I got mistake "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved" when try add product to card how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a mistake "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved", I can not add a product to the cart.

The error is in this line "order.line_items.create product: product,"

I have no idea what could be wrong.

Please help maybe you will see something.
Thank you in advance for your help.

helper method

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
helper_method :current_cart    
def current_cart
 if session[:order_id]
   Order.find(session[:order_id])
 else
   Order.new
 end
end

def current_cart_or_create
 c = current_cart
 if c.new_record?
   c.save
   session[:order_id] = c.id
 end
 c
end
```

Cart controller

```
  class CartController < ApplicationController
def show
  @cart = current_cart
end

def edit
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.build_address if @cart.address.blank?
end

def update
  @cart = current_cart
  if @cart.update_attributes(cart_attributes)
    @cart.update_attribute(:shipping_cost, @cart.shipping_type.cost)
    redirect_to confirmation_cart_path
  else
    render action: :edit
  end
end

def confirmation
  @cart = current_cart
end

def finish
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.transition_to :confirmed
  session.delete(:order_id)
  flash[:notice] = "Dziękujemy za zamówienie!"
  redirect_to root_path
end

def add_product
  order = current_cart_or_create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  if item = order.line_items.where(product: product).first
    item.quantity += 1
    item.save
  else
    order.line_items.create product: product,
    quantity: 1,
    unit_price: product.price,
    item_name: product.name
  end
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Dodano produkt do koszyka"
  #redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end

def remove_product
  order = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  item = order.line_items.where(product: product).first
  if item
    item.destroy
  end
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Usunięto produkt z koszyka"
end

private

def cart_attributes
  params.require(:order).permit(
    :shipping_type_id,
    :comment,
    :address_attributes => [
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :city,
      :zip_code,
      :street,
      :email
    ]
  )
end

end
```

Comment: Did order a saved resource? look, if the  `c.save` have some problem, you can have this error.

Comment: Plese, post your order and line items class

Answer (score 0):

Your `Order.new` is most probably not saved through your `c.save` because it does not pass the validations of your `Order` model.

Your logs probably show something like:

```
  (4.8ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

when it tries to execute `c.save`.
You should try to use `c.save!`instead, the logs should then show a detailled error like:
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank...`
Or just check your Order model to see which fields are mandatory (validations).

Then fill in the mandatory fields, for instance :

```
o = Order.new
o.name = "new order"
o
```

Then you should be able to save this new parent record and create records of the child model associated (`LineItems`)

Answer (score 0):

ok, i changed c.save to c.save! and get this error "Negative validation: The shipping type must exist rails"
After add "optional: true" everything works, but I need shipping_type to be required and not an optional one, how should I correct it?

Order class

```
  class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordQueries
belongs_to :shipping_type, optional: true
has_many :line_items
has_one :address
has_many :transitions, class_name: "OrderTransition", autosave: false

accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

delegate :can_transition_to?, :transition_to!, :transition_to, :current_state,
  to: :state_machine

def state_machine
  @state_machine ||= OrderStateMachine.new(self, transition_class: OrderTransition,
                                           association_name: :transitions)
end

def full_cost
  line_items.map { |e| e.full_price }.sum + shipping_cost
end

def self.transition_class
  OrderTransition
end

def self.initial_state
  OrderStateMachine.initial_state
end

def self.transition_name
  :transitions
end
end
```

Comment: Do you have an option to choose a shipping_type in your form?